# No Gradients Provided

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

My problematic network takes a `10x10x1` image as input and returns `4x2x3` image as output. Like so:
**Input to the network**
[image]

The input image has two patches of size `2x2x1`.

**Output of the network:**
My problematic network needs to extract output image of size `4x2x3`. Like so:

[image]

These above patches should be directly extracted from another image I'd call *Original image*.

**Original Image**
This is the original image, where from I need to extract the original patches. This original Image contains patches of size `4x2x3`

[image]

I extract the left top location of each patch in my last layer from `10x10x1` input image, which has the patches at approximately the same locations as those of the input image. But, these values are predicted, so may not be totally accurate. Once I have the top left location of the patches, I extract them from the `10x10x3` original image and output them. This output is fed to the loss function. It seems my gradients aren't flowing back and I am getting following error:

```
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables ["<tf.Variable 'cv/conv1_W:0' shape=(4, 4, 1, 16) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'cv/conv1_b:0' shape=(16,) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'fc/fc_1_W:0' shape=(400, 100) dtype=float32_ref>", "<tf.Variable 'fc/fc_1_b:0' shape=(100,) dtype=float32_ref>"] and loss Tensor("Mean:0", shape=(), dtype=float32).
```

However, if I extract the image from `10x10x1` input image, everything works fine. I need to extract the *locations* from `10x10x1` image, and then extract the actual patch contents from `10x10x3` original image. Locations may not be accurate always, so I need to train my network in order to improve the locations given in the input `10x10x1` image. So, I need to be able extract the patches, compute gradient, improve the weights, and try extracting again.

I am using Tensorflow and Conv Nets to perform this functionality. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.